# How to loop on a buffered channel without deadlocking?

Tags: concurrency, go, channel

I'm wondering how can I  drain / close the buffered  channels so that I don't get into the deadlock? I'm using range to loop through the channels but it seems that although they are "read" they don't get closed like the non-buffered channels do.

```
package main

func main() {

    cp := 2
    ch := make(chan string, cp)

    for i := 0; i < cp; i++ {
        go send(ch)
    }
    go send(ch)

    for lc := range ch {
        print(lc)

    }

}

func send(ch chan string) {

    ch <- "hello\n"

}
```

[Play](http://play.golang.org/p/GdBqQKbR1x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can close channels using the [`close()` builtin](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Close). This has to be called *after* all of your concurrent processing is done. How you're doing that depends on what you want to do.

In your current architecture it seems that you have to establish a global state, something that tracks all your processes and determines that the last one finished. Such a state can be achieved by using a [`sync.WaitGroup`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) for example.

```
func send(c chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    // ...
}

wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}

for i := 0; i < cp; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go send(ch, wg)
}
wg.Add(1)
go send(ch, wg)

wg.Wait()
close(ch)

for e := range(ch) {
    // ...
}
```

Note that closing the channel and then iterating over it will give you *only the elements that are queued in the channel*. This means that any goroutine that wanted to put a value in the channel can't do this anymore as the channel is closed.

Comment: Why is there ``wg.Add(1)`` above  ``go send(ch, wg)`` (after the for loop)? I think it's a typo, right ?

Comment: No typo. For each goroutine that modifies the channel you add a number to the waitgroup. Consider reading the examples in the documentation.

Comment: right ... I didn't see the go routine outside the  ``for`` loop.